# How to tell if an EKEvent instance is declined or not?

Tags: swift, macos, ekevent

I have a list of EKEvent's for the current day, and I want to filter out any that have been declined by the current user so that the list only contains

How can I do this? I can't find any examples anywhere, or any property on the event itself to store this info.

Here's some sample code, if that helps:

```js
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let today = Date()
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: today, end: tomorrow, calendars: nil)
let events = self.eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
// @TODO: Filter events by removing declined events.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the infos via attendees and then participantStatus -> declined

Comment: But that would be for all participants, right? Any idea how to find the participant that is the current user?

Comment: you can loop over attendees and check wether it is current user